# How to Rollback the asynchronously running prepared statement using Spring MVC and ORACLE

Tags: spring-mvc, prepared-statement

I am Asynchronously running the prepared statement to improve my application performance.At few scenarios the application throws exception.i am able catch the exceptions but i am not able to stop the asynchronously running prepared statement and rollback to the previous state.

Need: 1)Rollback to the existing state in all tables which are affected by Asynchronously runed the prepared statement

Note:Application is developed using Spring MVC and Oracle Database

Comment: If that results in multiple transactions there is no way you can rollback those other statements.

Comment: Every thing is under same transaction

Comment: If you expect multiple threads to be under the same transaction they aren't... Transactions are thread bound...